# At what stage should Dark Soy sauce be added while making noodles?

Tags: noodles, soy

I'm new to soy sauce and have heard that it's essential in chinese cuisine. But it doesn't seem to add any flavor to my noodles. I'm adding the sauce before I put my cooked noddles in. And what's the optimal quantity to add without darkening the color of the dish?

Comment: What dish are you making? "I'm adding the sauce before I put my cooked noodles in", in what? The optimal quantity to add will depend on the quantity you're making.

Answer (score 2):

The soy sauce can be used alone or added with other sauces like fish sauce, tomato sauce or squid sauce to enhance the flavor n color of the noodles. and remember there are two kinds of soy sauce one dark and the other light. you need to add the amount according to the dish you are planning, say for two serves two spoons will do good. And as u said its generally added to the veggies before adding the noodles to get even color. Doing the other way wont hurt thou' .